# AWS FIS does not work for Istio enabled applications

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar, istio-operator, aws-fis

AWS FIS eks experiments such as eks pod termination, pod cpu stress does not work for Istio enabled application. I have namespace for which istio-injection is enabled and application is running under that namespace. If I run pod delete FIS experiment I get below error:

```
ERROR: Error captured while executing... Post "https://x.x.x.x:443/api/v1/namespaces/prod/configmaps": dial tcp x.x.x.x:443: connect: connection refused
ERROR: Fault injection has failed with error:  Post "https://x.x.x.x:443/api/v1/namespaces/prod/configmaps": dial tcp x.x.x.x:443: connect: connection refused
```

AWS FIS works fine for Istio disabled applications.

I tried `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges: x.x.x.x/32` whitelisting IP address of kubernetes api but doesn't seems to help.